# Centre two rails link_to buttons next to each other

Tags: html, css, ruby-on-rails

I have two buttons created using the rails `link_to` helper:

```
<% if !@prev_task.nil? %>
  <p style="text-align:center;"><%= link_to "PREVIOUS TASK", [@prev_task.project, @prev_task], class: "btn btn-round color3" %>
<% end %>
<% if !@next_task.nil? %>
  <%= link_to "NEXT TASK", [@next_task.project, @next_task], class: "btn btn-round color3" %></p>
<% end %>
```

I have set it up to the `<p>` tag is at the start of one button and at the end of the second button.

What happens is based on the condition:

1. When the `NEXT TASK` button is the only visible button, it is not in
   the centre but to the left side of the screen (`not correct`).
2. When both button are on the screen, they are both aligned next to
   each other in the centre of the page as expected (`correct`)
3. When the `PREVIOUS TASK` button is only visible button, it is in the
   centre as it should be (`correct`)

So when the `NEXT TASK` button is the only button visible i need this in the centre of the page not to the left based on the `<p>` tag inline style.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am not familiar with ROR (yet) but I may guess that opened paragraph can close itself, but the closed paragraph can't open itself :)

Maybe you can put the opening paragraph tag and closing paragraph tag outside the conditions? And wrap all into yet another condition for the case if there is no prev/next at all (in order to hide empty paragraph)